# Determining the $Z$ boson invisible width using initial state radiation (ISR)

Tags: particle-physics, standard-model, particle-detectors

I have read (https://academic.oup.com/book/25938) &(https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-642-05169-2_3) that initial state radiation can be used to make a determination of the Z boson's invisible width, but I'm a bit confused as to the details of how exactly. Taking LEP as an example, a photon could be emitted by the incoming electron (positron). Let's say this leads to radiative return to the Z boson, and we get a Z boson that then decays to a neutrino and an anti-neutrino. We don't see these neutrinos, of course, but we do see the photon. We then count this event towards a measurement of the invisible width. But there seem to be some problems with this:

- What if the electron positron beams simply didn't interact, but an ISR photon was still
  produced--we'd then be counting an "event" in error.
- What about production of the Z boson and its subsequent decay to neutrino antineutrino
  *without* ISR. We'd not see this and would then underestimate the invisible width.
- These ISR photons must be strongly Lorentz boosted. Is there not a danger of losing them down the beam pipe?

Are these all real concerns or is there something I'm misunderstanding? Perhaps using the probabilities for ISR to occur and a Monte Carlo simulation, these things can be accounted for?

Comment: You should give a reference for your "I have read", a link would help more. Relevant to invisible width,  https://cms.cern/news/tale-two-colliders-and-unrivalled-precision-z-invisible-width

Comment: Minor comment to the post (v3): Please consider to mention explicitly author, title, etc. of link, so it is possible to reconstruct link in case of link rot.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know the answer for sure, so more knowledgeable people, if they come along, should upvote or downvote this if its right/wrong, but I have suggestions for each of your proposals.

(1) maybe the ISR photon in question is a photon with transverse momentum. The usual argument with transverse momentum is "since the particles in the beam only have parallel momentum, if the final state appears to have transverse momentum, it's because we didn't detect some other particles with transverse momentum"

(2) The question isn't the total cross section for $e^+ + e^-\rightarrow Z^0\rightarrow \nu+\bar{\nu}$, it's just the decay rate for $Z^0\rightarrow \nu+\bar{\nu}$. So you only need to measure the total $Z^0$ lifetime, and the fraction of $Z^0$ that decay to $\nu+\bar{\nu}$, and you'd have your desired measurement. So in the measurement scheme from (1), you could see how many ISR photons with transverse momentum are paired with (for example) a $\mu^+ +\mu^-$ produced by the decaying Z versus how many ISR photons with transverse momentum are paired with nothing, and you could find the fraction of Z decays that go to neutrinos.

(3) see (1), only ISR photons with transverse momentum help you to identify a state with neutrinos anyway, so it will enter the detector, since transverse momentum means it isn't travelling along the beam pipe.

Comment: For (1), would it not still be possible to get a transverse ISR photon without getting an interaction between the beams? The photon would just give a kick to the electron (say), which might not deviate very much at all. We'd then be counting these as nu nu events and it would mess up the fraction in (2). This wouldn't be a problem for the Z to muon decays as it would be obvious when there was an interaction.

Comment: @Arthur if you define "significant transverse momentum" as "a significant fraction of the incoming electron's parallel momentum," then you don't have this problem. In order to produce a significantly transverse photon, you either need to deflect the beam particle far enough that it will hit the detector or you need to produce a Z that has significant transverse momentum. Again, IDK if this is the experimental reality, just a possibility